# Store output from a for loop into a String

Tags: java, string, loops

I want to store the questionmarks in a string because later I will be using string replace method to replace those question marks with a character the user guess. This is kind of a hangman game.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length;
    String originalString;
    String option= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String questionmarks;

    System.out.println("Please enter a string");
    originalString=keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println(originalString);

    length=originalString.length();
    for(int i=1; i<=length;i++){
        System.out.print("?");
    }




}
```

Comment: You have not provided a problem statement.

Comment: Do you want as much number of `?` as the length of the string?

Comment: yes, that what the loop does. Prints out ? of length of the string.

Comment: is this all you want to do ?=> `for(int i=1; i<=length;i++){
        questionmarks += "?";
    }`

Comment: The question is once i get the question marks, i want to store them into a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
questionmarks = originalString.replaceAll(".", "?");
```

i.e. replace every character (`.`) with a `?`. This eliminates the need for an explicit `for`-loop.

---

For example:

```
String originalString = "abcd";
String questionmarks = originalString.replaceAll(".", "?");

System.out.println(questionmarks);
```

```
????
```

Comment: In case anyone is horribly confused why replacing periods actually replaces letters, `replaceAll` uses regex.

Comment: Yeah i will accept the answer once the time is up, pretty straight answer. I didn't do this because we never learned this method in class. :S